# Put Site-Wide Contact Form in a Block

Tags: 7, emails

I want to display the contact form inside a block, so that a user can access it directly from another page. Using [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) Module to create a new form would be overkill.

Is there a simple way to do this, either core, a small module or custom module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) module. Enables the presentation of user registration, **site wide contact**, or node creation forms in blocks.

Comment: Hi @user842 i tried using this. I added a page with two sections one with custom block and one with site-wide-contact form. I can see those 2 sections only when i am logined as admin. But if i logout and check the page, it only shows custom block. I cannot see site wide contact form any where. Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with webform, take a look at this [link](http://drupal.org/node/1447436), it tells you exactly what to do to enable it.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using:

- hook_form_info() to define the block you want to add.
- hook_block_view($delta) to define the content you wish to add to your block. Basically just add this

  ```
  $block = [];

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'block_contact_form':
      module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
      $block['subject'] = t('Contact');
      $block['content']['form'] = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
    break;
  }

  return $block;
  ```