# How to display contact form module in a block using drupal 7

Tags: emails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put Site-Wide Contact Form in a Block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18893/put-site-wide-contact-form-in-a-block)

I want to display the contact form in a sidebar of the website. Is it possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18895/2792) which recommends to use [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) module.
[This](http://www.viktormiranda.com/blog/drupal-7-contact-block) could also be useful.

Answer (score -3):

I think this feature is not included in the contact module of Drupal. It means it is still possible, but you have to add code to the module, where you implement the contact form in a Drupal block.